# Integrating Next.js Font Variables with Storybook in a TailwindCSS-Enabled Next.js Application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fonts, tailwind-css, storybook

I'm working on a Next.js application that uses App Router and is styled with TailwindCSS. Additionally, I've integrated Storybook for component development. My issue lies in integrating custom fonts with Storybook.

I've added custom font variables in my `layout.tsx` using `Next/Font` like so:

```
// layout.tsx
import { Alata, DM_Serif_Display, Open_Sans } from 'next/font/google';

const alata = Alata({
  weight: '400',
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-alata'
});
const openSans = Open_Sans({
  variable: '--font-open-sans',
  subsets: ['latin-ext']
});
const dmSerif = DM_Serif_Display({
  weight: '400',
  variable: '--font-dm-serif',
  subsets: ['latin-ext']
});

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode; }) {
  return (
    <html lang="pl">
      <body className={`${alata.variable} ${openSans.variable} ${dmSerif.variable}`}>
        {children}
        {/* Other components */}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I then extended the font family in my tailwind.config.js:

```
// tailwind.config.ts
module.exports = {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['var(--font-open-sans)', 'sans-serif'],
      alata: ['var(--font-alata)', 'sans-serif'],
      display: ['var(--font-dm-serif)', 'sans-serif'],
    },
  },
  // Other configurations
};
```

However, when using Storybook, these font variables are not being injected into the body. It seems that the Next/Font component, which is responsible for building and injecting these during build time, doesn't work as expected with Storybook.

Could someone suggest the best approach to ensure that these font variables are available and correctly applied in Storybook? Any tips or insights on integrating Next.js font configurations with Storybook in a TailwindCSS environment would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your layout, you are defining the css variables for the fonts, but not actually using them. If you want your app to render the font, you will have to add the appropriate tailwind [font-family utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#setting-the-font-family) to your html:

```
<body className={`font-sans ${openSans.variable}`}>
```

To get storybook to render the correct font, assuming you're using [`@storybook/nextjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs), you need to somehow add the font-family utility class (i.e. `font-sans`) and css variable class (i.e. `openSans.variable`) to the body as above. As storybook doesn't seem to support styling the body directly, one way to achieve a similar effect is by using a [global decorator](https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/decorators#global-decorators).

```
// .storybook/preview.tsx

import React from "react";
import "../src/styles/globals.css";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { Open_Sans as FontSans } from "next/font/google";

const fontSans = FontSans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-sans",
});

const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div className={`font-sans ${fontSans.variable}`}>
        <Story />
      </div>
    ),
  ],
};

export default preview;
```

You can extract the `next/font/google` code to a separate file and import it from both the layout and preview files like suggested [here](https://towardsdev.com/configure-next-js-fonts-with-tailwind-in-storybook-f51541ad77de).